# Create a new columns to show the month of last spend in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am working on a spend data where I want to see the last month when the spend was made in current and previous year. If there is no spend in these years, then, I assume the last month of spend as Dec-2020.

My data looks like this

[image]

As shown in the data the months are already there in the form of columns.
I want to create a new column `last_txn_month` which gives last month when the spend was made. So the output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't see numbers on images - the are too small. Better put it as text - so we could copy and use it in solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your DataFrame looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                   [101, 102, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                   [110, np.nan, np.nan, 111, np.nan]], 
                  columns=[*'abcde'])
```

Then you could use `notna` to create boolean DataFrame; then `apply` a lambda function that filters the last column name of a  non-NaN value for each row:

```
df['last'] = df.notna().apply(lambda x: df.columns[x][-1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     a      b     c      d     e last
0    1    NaN   NaN    3.0   NaN    d
1   10   11.0  12.0   13.0  14.0    e
2  101  102.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    b
3  110    NaN   NaN  111.0   NaN    d
```